# Google Apps Script not outputting returned results to sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following code, the purpose of which is to try and get some useful insight into the last login/activity information from Google as the 'last login date' metric isn't the most reliable.

```
const testState = true;

function generateUserReport() {
  let state;

  if ((test = true)) {
    state = "Frodo.Baggins@domain.com";
  } else if ((test = false)) {
    state = "all";
  } else {
    throw "State not defined";
  }

  Logger.log("Test State: "+ testState)

  const daysToCheck = 4;
  const now = new Date();
  const daysAgo = new Date(now.getTime() - daysToCheck * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  const timezone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
  const date = Utilities.formatDate(daysAgo, timezone, "yyyy-MM-dd");
  const parameters = [
    "accounts:first_name",
    "accounts:last_name",
    "accounts:last_login_time",
    "gmail:timestamp_last_access",
    "gmail:timestamp_last_imap",
    "gmail:timestamp_last_interaction",
    "gmail:timestamp_last_pop",
    "gmail:timestamp_last_webmail",
    "drive:timestamp_last_active_usage"
  ];
  const rows = [];
  let pageToken;
  let page;

  do {
    page = AdminReports.UserUsageReport.get(state, date, {
      parameters: parameters.join(","),
      maxResults: 500,
      pageToken
    });

    if (page.warnings) {
      for (var i = 0; i < page.warnings.length; i++) {
        const warning = page.warnings[i];
        Logger.log(warning.message);
      }
    }

    const reports = page.usageReports;

    if (reports) {
      for (var i = 0; i < reports.length; i++) {
        const report = reports[i];
        const parameterValues = getParameterValues(report.parameters);
        const row = [
          report.date,
          report.entity.userEmail,
          parameterValues["accounts:first_name"],
          parameterValues["accounts:last_name"],
          parameterValues["accounts:last_login_time"],
          parameterValues["gmail:timestamp_last_access"],
          parameterValues["gmail:timestamp_last_imap"],
          parameterValues["gmail:timestamp_last_interaction"],
          parameterValues["gmail:timestamp_last_pop"],
          parameterValues["gmail:timestamp_last_webmail"],
          parameterValues["drive:timestamp_last_active_usage"]
        ];
        Logger.log("Logging row: \n"+row);
        rows.push(row);
        Logger.log("Logging rows after push: \n"+rows);
      }
    }

    pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);

  if (rows.length > 0) {
    const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    const sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("User Access Report");
    sheet.clear(); // Append the headers.

    const headers = [
      "Date",
      "User",
      "First Name",
      "Last Name",
      "Account Last Login",
      "Email Last Access",
      "Email Interaction",
      "IMAP",
      "POP",
      "WEBMAIL",
      "DRIVE"
    ];
    sheet.appendRow(headers);
    
    // Append the results.
    sheet.getRange(2, 1, rows.length, rows[0].length).setValues(rows);
    Logger.log("Report spreadsheet completed");
    
    // Send notification email on completion
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: "my.email@domain.com",
      subject: "The account Usage Report has completed",
      htmlBody: `The script to get user account usage has completed.<br><br>Please click here view view it:<br>${spreadsheet.getUrl()}`,
      name: "Script Helper"
    });
  } else {
    Logger.log("No results returned.");
  }
}
/**
 * Gets a map of parameter names to values from an array of parameter objects.
 * @param {Array} parameters An array of parameter objects.
 * @return {Object} A map from parameter names to their values.
 */

function getParameterValues(parameters) {
  return parameters.reduce((result, parameter) => {
    const name = parameter.name; 
    
    let value;

    if (parameter.intValue !== undefined) {
      value = parameter.intValue;
    } else if (parameter.stringValue !== undefined) {
      value = parameter.stringValue;
    } else if (parameter.datetimeValue !== undefined) {
      value = new Date(parameter.datetimeValue);
    } else if (parameter.boolValue !== undefined) {
      value = parameter.boolValue;
    }

    result[name] = value;
    Logger.log(`${name} Result: ${result[name]}`);
    return result;
  }, {});
}
```

It works, in part - but for some reason, it doesn't pull all of the returned information into the spreadsheet.

Columns A - E (headers: Date, User, First Name, Last Name, Account Last Login) all populate in the sheet as expected, however columns F-K (headers: Email Last Access, Email Interaction, IMAP, POP, WEBMAIL, DRIVE) do not populate at all and return null for some reason (despite the logging showing it finds values).

I have logged out each call of the `getParameterValues` function, and I can see that it is pulling the correct information, however, when I log out the row and rows it shows null. As far as I can see, it should work... so I'm confused and hoping that someone else can help or offer some advice?

Log below to show the results:

```
3:50:24 PM  Notice  Execution started
3:50:24 PM  Info    Test State: true
3:50:25 PM  Info    accounts:first_name Result: Frodo
3:50:25 PM  Info    accounts:last_name Result: Baggins
3:50:25 PM  Info    accounts:last_login_time Result: Wed Feb 24 2021 04:57:24 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
3:50:25 PM  Info    gmail:last_access_time Result: Sat Feb 27 2021 01:37:20 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
3:50:25 PM  Info    gmail:last_interaction_time Result: Fri Feb 26 2021 04:07:14 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
3:50:25 PM  Info    gmail:last_webmail_time Result: Fri Feb 26 2021 12:41:25 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
3:50:25 PM  Info    drive:last_active_usage_time Result: Fri Feb 26 2021 12:37:31 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
3:50:25 PM  Info    Logging row: 
2021-02-26,Frodo.Baggins@domain.co.uk,Frodo,Baggins,Wed Feb 24 2021 04:57:24 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time),,,,,,
3:50:25 PM  Info    Logging rows after push: 
2021-02-26,Frodo.Baggins@domain.co.uk,Frodo,Baggins,Wed Feb 24 2021 04:57:24 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time),,,,,,
3:50:27 PM  Info    Report spreadsheet completed
3:50:28 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out that the returned values are named differently.

Here is the completed script for anyone who needs something similar in the future:

```
//Set to true if developing/testing - if running a live version, set to false
let testState = false;

function generateUserReport() {
  let target; 
  
  //Check if dev or prod and change values as required
  if (testState == true) {
    target = "Frodo.Baggins@domain.com";
  } else if (testState == false) {
    target = "all";
  } else {
    throw "State not defined";
  }

  Logger.log("Test State: " + testState);

  const daysToCheck = 14;
  const now = new Date();
  const daysAgo = new Date(now.getTime() - daysToCheck * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  const timezone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
  const date = Utilities.formatDate(daysAgo, timezone, "yyyy-MM-dd");
  const parameters = [
    "accounts:first_name",
    "accounts:last_name",
    "accounts:last_login_time",
    "gmail:timestamp_last_access",
    "gmail:timestamp_last_interaction",
    "gmail:timestamp_last_imap",
    "gmail:timestamp_last_pop",
    "gmail:timestamp_last_webmail",
    "drive:timestamp_last_active_usage"
  ];
  const rows = [];
  let pageToken;
  let page;

  Logger.log("Target for API call: " + target);

  do {
    page = AdminReports.UserUsageReport.get(target, date, {
      parameters: parameters.join(","),
      maxResults: 500,
      pageToken
    });

    if (page.warnings) {
      for (var i = 0; i < page.warnings.length; i++) {
        const warning = page.warnings[i];
        Logger.log(warning.message);
      }
    }

    const reports = page.usageReports;

    if (reports) {
      for (var i = 0; i < reports.length; i++) {
        const report = reports[i];
        const parameterValues = getParameterValues(report.parameters);
        const row = [
          report.date,
          report.entity.userEmail,
          parameterValues["accounts:first_name"],
          parameterValues["accounts:last_name"],
          parameterValues["accounts:last_login_time"],
          parameterValues["gmail:last_access_time"],
          parameterValues["gmail:last_interaction_time"],
          parameterValues["gmail:last_imap_time"],
          parameterValues["gmail:last_pop_time"],
          parameterValues["gmail:last_webmail_time"],
          parameterValues["drive:last_active_usage_time"]
        ];

        //If testing, log row
        if (testState == true) {
          Logger.log("Logging row: \n" + row);
        } else {
        }

        rows.push(row);

        //If testing, log rows
        if (testState == true) {
          Logger.log("Logging rows after push: \n" + rows);
        } else {
        }
      }
    }

    pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);

  if (rows.length > 0) {
    const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    const sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("User Access Report");
    sheet.clear(); // Append the headers.

    const headers = [
      "Date",
      "User",
      "First Name",
      "Last Name",
      "Account Last Login",
      "Email Last Access",
      "Email Interaction",
      "IMAP",
      "POP",
      "WEBMAIL",
      "DRIVE"
    ];
    sheet.appendRow(headers);
    
    // Append the results.
    sheet.getRange(2, 1, rows.length, rows[0].length).setValues(rows);
    Logger.log("Report spreadsheet completed");
    
    // Send notification email on completion
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: "my.email@domain.com",
      subject: "The account Usage Report has completed",
      htmlBody: `The script to get user account usage has completed.<br><br>Please click here view view it:<br>${spreadsheet.getUrl()}`,
      name: "Script Helper"
    });
  } else {
    Logger.log("No results returned.");
  }
}
/**
 * Gets a map of parameter names to values from an array of parameter objects.
 * @param {Array} parameters An array of parameter objects.
 * @return {Object} A map from parameter names to their values.
 */

function getParameterValues(parameters) {
  return parameters.reduce((result, parameter) => {
    const name = parameter.name;
    let value;

    if (parameter.intValue !== undefined) {
      value = parameter.intValue;
    } else if (parameter.stringValue !== undefined) {
      value = parameter.stringValue;
    } else if (parameter.datetimeValue !== undefined) {
      value = new Date(parameter.datetimeValue);
    } else if (parameter.boolValue !== undefined) {
      value = parameter.boolValue;
    }

    result[name] = value;

    //If testing, logout the results
    if (testState == true) {
      Logger.log(`${name} Result: ${result[name]}`);
    } else {
    }

    return result;
  }, {});
}
```

Note how the returned values are 'last_' :

```
  parameterValues["gmail:last_access_time"],
  parameterValues["gmail:last_interaction_time"],
  parameterValues["gmail:last_imap_time"],
  parameterValues["gmail:last_pop_time"],
  parameterValues["gmail:last_webmail_time"],
  parameterValues["drive:last_active_usage_time"]
```

And not 'timestamp_last_' :

```
"gmail:timestamp_last_access",
"gmail:timestamp_last_interaction",
"gmail:timestamp_last_imap",
"gmail:timestamp_last_pop",
"gmail:timestamp_last_webmail",
"drive:timestamp_last_active_usage"
```

As I was trying to use in my original script.

So there is a completed version of it if anyone else needs it.
This is much more reliable that just using Google's 'last login' metric.
I added a column into my sheet in Column L that uses the formula: `=MAX(E2:K2)` to get the most recent date for the user.

Answer (score 1):

That is very strange. It seems to be an issue with the keys of the `parameterValues`.

If you build the row Array in the following way, then the values which aren't really undefined and are printed to the sheet:

### Example:

```js
const row = [
    report.date,
    report.entity.userEmail
];
Object.keys(parameterValues).forEach((key) => {
    row.push(parameterValues[key])
});
```